# Puppet: Replacing create_resources() with hash iteration

Tags: puppet, ruby, configuration-management

We're migrating from Puppet 2 to 5. It seems the scoping is a little different. Before, when using `create_resources()` with a hiera_hash and a default hash, variables from within the calling script were available to the ERB, but now they don't seem to be. For example, I could set `$a = 'hello world'` in the calling script right before `create_resources()`, and then within my ERB, I could simply reference `$a` and get back `hello world`. That doesn't seem to be the case now.

So the idea is to abandon `create_resources()` and use Puppet 5's `each` function on the `hiera_hash` just creating a new file within the loop. However, I'm having trouble merging the default values to each hash element. I'm not able to redeclare variables, so I can't do a merge within the loop it seems.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

**Data.file1.yaml**

```
my::data:
  element_a:
    fname: 'Brian'
    lname: 'Detweiler'
  element_b:
    fname: 'Joe'
    lname: 'Schmoe'
```

**Data.default.yaml**

```
my::defaults
  mname: 'M.'
```

Before I would pull both of those in as `hiera_hash`s and do `create_resources('my::template::script', $names, $names_default)` and I would end up with the expected merges:

```
'element_a' => { fname => 'Brian', lname => 'Detweiler', mname => 'M.'},
'element_b' => { fname => 'Joe', lname => 'Schmoe', mname => 'M.'}
```

Now I want to do

```
$names.each | String $key, Hash $value | {
  $merged_hash_val = $names_default + $value
  file {
    # ... create file with $merged_hash_val in here
  }
}
```

But since variables are immutable, I can't reassign values. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Variables are still accessible to the template. I am concerned that there is something else going on there. You might not want to change your `create_resources()` usage if you address that. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables

Comment: @AaronCopley Ok, so it looks like I can still access the variable, I just have to use `scope` and fully qualify it. Before, I was able to access any of the variables in the call chain by just doing `@variable`, but now I have to do `scope['my::calling_script::variable']`. Thanks, I think this will work. Submit as an answer and I'll accept. :)

Comment: If it's in the same namespace you shouldn't need to scope it, but glad that solved your problem.

Comment: I may not have been super clear in my question, but my main script calls `create_resources()` which calls another puppet script, which then creates a `file` resource, using the ERB template. The variables I was after are in the main script, so basically 2 hops away. Which I believe means it would not be in the same namespace.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense! You'll have to use scope as you've found. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are still accessible to the template. I am concerned that there is something else going on there. You might not want to change your `create_resources()` usage if you address that.

See: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables

Answer (score 0):

FTR

```
$names.each | String $key, Hash $value | {
  $merged_hash_val = $names_default + $value
  file {
    * => $merged_hash_val
  }
}
```

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_resources.html#lang_resource_syntax-setting-attributes-from-hash